# Getting values from large JSON to display

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to get just the Name out of the JSON object for each of the customers.  Displaying a list of names available so that a person can select one, which will then populate a form with name, address, phone, etc.

```
btn.onclick = function() {
    modal.style.display = "block";

    var Sdata = document.getElementById('search').value; 
    $.ajax({
            url: "search1.php",
            search:Sdata
        }).done(function(data) {
            var jObject = JSON.parse(data);

            for (var key in jObject) {
                if (jObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    document.getElementById("modalContent").innerHTML = (key + "->" + jObject[key]); //insert data into modal
                    for (var key in p) {
                        if (jObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        }
                    }
                 }
             }
        });
}
```

And the HTML is

```
<form id="searchbox" action="search1.php">                
  <input id="search" name="search" type="text"   
         placeholder="Search by Name">
  <input id="myBtn" type="button" value="Search" >

  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>Test Drives</h2>
    <div id="modalContent">


    </div> 
  </div>
</form>
```

I hope you can help. :)

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: may be add your sample json in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I ended up using was this, though itzmukeshy7 answer was where I started.

```
$.each(jObject, function(key, value) {
  $('#'+ key).bind('click', {obj:value}, function(event){
       var driver=event.data.obj;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this ;)

```
var jObject = JSON.parse(data);
for (var key in jObject) {
  document.getElementById("modalContent").innerHTML += (key + "->" + jObject[key]); //insert data into modal
}
```

Here you are overwriting `innerHTML` don't do that just append content to existing content using `+`;